# Display articles from other Joomla site

Tags: php, joomla

I have 13 sites in Joomla installed on one server.
One main site + 12 other sites.
Each site is a diffrent Joomla installation (based on the same template etc.)

Now I need to display news from **Main Site** in **Other sites**.

I'm thinking about:

1. Do this by RSS but I have a news slider and it doesn't support RSS chanles.
2. Make PHP script, when I inserting article on main site, insert article directly to databases of other 12 sites.
3. Make custom script to parse content from main site and load like news in other sites.

Do you have any ideas? How to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just make 1 php script to **read** from 12 databases instead of replicate data everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the website databases in question are on the same server I would directly query the relevant tables instead of going through all the trouble and overhead of setting up 12 different RSS feeds. This is assuming there is no other business need to implement those feeds to the outside world.

Check out the below link on how to connect to external databases using Joomla's core database classes.  Depending on how you structure, you could write one module with connection, table and query options that can be installed on all websites.  This allows you to accomplish your goals for all websites while only having to maintain one modules code package.

http://docs.joomla.org/Connecting_to_an_external_database

Comment: Thanks for answer, that's the solution :)